# MySQL alter table modify column failing at rows with null values

Tags: mysql

I have a table with about 10K rows, which I am trying to alter so that the field `fielddelimiter` is never null. I am attempting to do an alter statement, expecting any null values to be changed to the default value, but I get an error back from the sql statement.

```
alter table merchant_ftp_account modify column `fielddelimiter` char(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT 't';

17:08:48  [ALTER - 0 row(s), 0.000 secs]  [Error Code: 1265, SQL State: 01000]  Data truncated for column 'fielddelimiter' at row 3987
... 1 statement(s) executed, 0 row(s) affected, exec/fetch time: 0.000/0.000 sec  [0 successful, 0 warnings, 1 errors]
```

As I understand it this means that the data exceeds the field size at this row, but (a) the data in the field is (null) at that row, and (b) I am able to update that row directly with the value 't', and I don't get a truncation error. If I update that row with a nonnull value and try to re-run the alter statement, it fails at the next row where `fielddelimiter` is null. [ETA: I get that MySQL *could* update in any direction, but I can actually track its progress as I change rows.]

There's a warning in the MySQL docs:

```
Warning This conversion may result in alteration of data. For example, if you shorten a
string column, values may be truncated. To prevent the operation from succeeding if
conversions to the new data type would result in loss of data, enable strict SQL mode
before using ALTER TABLE (see Section 5.1.6, “Server SQL Modes”).
```

But the values that it's supposedly truncating are nulls. Can anybody explain to me what is going on here? And how to resolve it?

[ETA: The existing `fielddelimiter` field definition is char(1) (allows nulls, no default value), so it should not have values > 1 char, and a select confirms that it does not. The distinct values in the field are NULL, '' (empty string), 'p', 't', and 'y'.]

Comment: I'd like to add that I have also tried to do an update to all rows where this field is null, and the query takes forever (so far I have stopped it running after 10 and 15 mins). My update is:
`update merchant_ftp_account set fielddelimiter = 't' where fielddelimiter IS NULL;`

Comment: what is the type of your field? if your type is something that can hold a bigger value, i guess, mysql is thinking that there are bigger values present in the column.

Comment: if your update is slow, make an index on the column and then try the update stmt.

Comment: @Ravi: Indexes improve _lookup_ time. You can't magically make writes faster. And, in fact, if anything your suggestion makes things slower as the index has to be rebuilt. Indexes are a tool that should be used with precision, not blindly and bluntly thrown at any problem you encounter in the vague hope that they'll magically "speed up my query"

Comment: building indexes on 10k rows should not take forever! since the update stmt is using a WHERE clause..there is a lookup involved isn't it?

Comment: Indeed. Updates (can) use lookups too. An index could help here. But I think this is a different question alltogether. Maybe we should focus on the original one.

Comment: @RaviBhatt - I probably should have mentioned that the type of the field before attempting to alter the table is char(1). The only changes I am making are not allowing nulls, and providing a default value.

Comment: what happens if you replace NULL values with your default value with an update statement and then do the ALTER TABLE?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I have just encountered this error, and it seems the solution was to use the `IGNORE` statement:

```
ALTER IGNORE TABLE `table` CHANGE COLUMN `col` `col` int(11) NOT NULL;
```

Note that you may still have data truncation issues, so be sure this is the desired result. Using the IGNORE statement it will suppress the data truncated errors for NULL values in columns (and possibly other errors!!!)

Comment: This may solve part of the problem, but no way I'm doing this on a production data set...  (I just encountered the original poster's problem in a database I'm working on, I have about 10k rows, but no slowdowns doing updates)

Comment: `ALTER IGNORE` is absolutely not recommended!

Answer (score 8):

If your column has NULL values, you can't alter it to be "NON NULL". Change the NULL values first to something else, then try it.

Comment: That's not the issue. If you specify a default value (as the OP does), NULL values automatically get updated to this default value.

Comment: ok, my bad, @Golez is right that that is not the issue.  FYI when I tried this, the NULL values were set to an empty string, not to the new default value.  But perhaps it is different if there was an old default value as well.

Comment: +1 This seems to be the correct answer for my MySQL settings (which I thought were fairly default for server)  I just managed to fix a "broken" database by setting the defaults prior to calling the alter table expression.

Comment: @GolezTrol I neither found reference on docs about this, but actually it was that.

Comment: This was my issue. I was trying to shorten a varchar column and make it non-null at the same time. There were nulls but that caused this misleading error about truncation, of which there was none.

Answer (score 4):

First remove any null values

```
UPDATE merchant_ftp_account SET fielddelimiter='t' WHERE fielddelimiter IS NULL;
```

Then

```
ALTER TABLE merchant_ftp_account MODIFY COLUMN `fielddelimiter` char(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT 't';
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case I was setting the column to **NOT NULL**

```
ALTER TABLE `request_info` 
CHANGE COLUMN `col_2` `col_2` 
VARCHAR(2000) 
NOT NULL -- here was setting it to NULL when the existing col allowed NULL
AFTER `col_1`
```

when previously I set the column to **DEFAULT NULL** (i.e. allow NULL values), so if you want to allow NULL then you can do the following:

```
ALTER TABLE `request_info` 
CHANGE COLUMN `col_2` `col_2` 
VARCHAR(2000) 
DEFAULT NULL -- changed from NOT --> DEFAULT 
AFTER `col_1`
```